# Error detection from Powershell Invoke-Sqlcmd not always working?

Tags: sql, powershell, error-handling

The database is updated by executing a list of queries that are located in a folder.

I need to be able to detect *any* errors that would also result in "Query completed with errors" in SQL Server Management Studio.

The following works to detect the "Invalid Object" error:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> $ErrorActionPreference
Stop
PS SQLSERVER:\> $Error.Clear()
PS SQLSERVER:\> $Error
PS SQLSERVER:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance .\SQLEXPRESS -Database Test -Query "select * from doesnotexist" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
PS SQLSERVER:\> $Error.Exception
Invalid object name 'doesnotexist'.
PS SQLSERVER:\>
```

Doing the same for select 1/0 does *not* work:

```
PS SQLSERVER:\> $ErrorActionPreference
Stop
PS SQLSERVER:\> $Error.Clear()
PS SQLSERVER:\> $Error
PS SQLSERVER:\> Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance .\SQLEXPRESS -Database Test -Query "select 1/0" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
PS SQLSERVER:\> $Error.Exception
PS SQLSERVER:\>
```

I would expect this to result in a "Divide by zero error encountered" error just like in SSMS.

Not detecting this particular error makes me wonder if other errors will also remain undetected.

Any idea why this is a happening and how I can make sure the *all* errors will be detected?

**UPDATE**

It turns out that I do not have Invoke-Sqlcmd available on the server I am installing, so on second thought I have to use sqlcmd.exe.

I think this is working for me:

```
$tempfile = [io.path]::GetTempFileName()
$cmd = [string]::Format("sqlcmd -S {0} -U {1} -P {2} -d {3} -i {4} -b > $tempfile",
    $g_connectionstring."Data Source",
    $g_connectionstring."User ID",
    $g_connectionstring."Password",
    $g_connectionstring."Initial Catalog",
    $path)
Invoke-Expression -Command $cmd
if ($LASTEXITCODE)
{
    $err = Get-Content $tempfile | Out-String
    Corax-Message "SQL" "Error" $err
    exit
}
Remove-Item $tempfile
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Regardless of the ErrorAction setting, invoke-sqlcmd cmdlet has a bug present in SQL Server 2008, 2008 R2 and 2012 versions of the cmdlet where T-SQL errors like divide by 0 do not cause an error. I logged a connect item on this and you can see details here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/779320/invoke-sqlcmd-does-not-return-t-sql-errors

Note: the issue is fixed in SQL 2014, however it does not appear a fix has been or will be provided for previous versions.

Comment: Thanks, that would explain why I am not seeing *any* error.

Comment: I just noticed that I only have the Microsoft® Command Line Utilities 11 for SQL Server® available on the VM that I am running the script on, so only sqlcmd.exe and no Invoke-Sqlcmd. So I have to figure out how to catch the errors from sqlcmd.exe in Powershell. But I guess that is another story...

Comment: Perhaps this will help you, my sqlcmd.exe Powershell wrapper: http://sev17.com/2012/11/12/sqlcmd-is-dead-long-live-sqlcmd/

Answer (score 4):

You are ignoring erros by using `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`, change that to `-ErrorAction Stop`.

**Edit:**

Turns out if you want error handling don't use `Invoke-SqlCmd` (http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/05/06/10-tips-for-the-sql-server-powershell-scripter.aspx)

You can use `GenericSqlQuery` function from this answer:[Powershell SQL SELECT output to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714531/powershell-sql-select-output-to-variable/22715645#22715645)
which throws errors correctly.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned in another answer by Raf; main reason for not detecting the error is  `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` (cause you are bypassing the error). If you even omit this option altogether; you will see the expected error

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance .\SQLEXPRESS -Database Test -Query "select 1/0"
```

You can as well use other error option like

> Stop running on an error -AbortOnError
>
> Display errors -OutputSqlErrors

It's all mentioned in relevant MSDN document. take a look [Invoke-Sqlcmd cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281720.aspx)